# Installing ffmpeg module for php on windows server

Tags: php, windows, ffmpeg

I got

> PHP Fatal error: Class 'ffmpeg_movie not found

I found several archives with php_ffmpeg.dll also I have add `extension=php_ffmpeg.dll` in php.ini, restart the apache but nothing related with **ffmpeg** shows up when check phpinfo()

My server is running on Windows and I need help with installing that library.

I just look in error.log and found following line

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to
>   load dynamic library
>   'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_ffmpeg.dll'
>   - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
>   but the dll file is there

Comment: Is your DLL library compatible with your PHP version ?

Comment: Don't know but I have try several dll files... My php is version 5.3.1

Comment: maybe try with the latest php5.2

Comment: Is the extension library actually present? In other words, is there a `php_ffmpeg.dll` in `C:\xampp\php\ext` ? I'm not sure if it ships with PHP by default.

Answer (score 0):

1. It may be that the server process does not have access rights to the file
2. Try it on cli first, you can debug that better - try

> $ php -m

to list all modules